# Render a template from command line using Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I have a Jenkins shell script which has something like this to create a Nginx configuration from a template.

`nginx.conf.j2`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name {{ server_name }};
  ...
```

The rendering process which passes all the environment variables to the template:

```
env server_name=$SERVER_NAME \
  python - <<'EOF' > "nginx.conf"
import os, jinja2
template = jinja2.Template(open(os.environ["nginx.conf.j2"]).read())
print template.render(**os.environ)
EOF
```

How to do the same using Ansible? I guess it could be something like:

```
ansible <host-pattern> -m template -a "src=nginx.conf.j2 dest=nginx.conf"
```

But how to skip `<host-pattern>` to do it locally? How to pass environment variables to the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to force Ansible to run locally you can either create an [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) file that just has localhost in it like this:

```
[local]
localhost ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local
```

Assuming you saved that into a file called `local` you would then use this like so:

```
ansible all -i local -m template -a "src=nginx.conf.j2 dest=nginx.conf"
```

Alternatively you can also so use the slightly hacky way round of providing an inventory as a list directly on the CLI:

```
ansible all -i "localhost," -m template -a "src=nginx.conf.j2 dest=nginx.conf" --connection=local
```

Specifically notice the trailing `,` as this makes Ansible see it as a list rather than a string and it expects inventories to be lists.

However, it sounds like you're trying to use Ansible as a drop in replacement for the Python snippet you included in your question. If you try the above (as mentioned in the comments) you will also see that Ansible only supports templates in playbooks and not in ad-hoc commands.

Instead I'd suggest you step back a little and use Ansible more as it was intended and use Jenkins to trigger an Ansible playbook with a specified inventory (that includes your Nginx box) that then configures Nginx.

A really basic example playbook might look something like this:

```
- hosts: nginx-servers
  tasks:
    - name: Template nginx.conf
      template:
        src: nginx.conf.j2
        dest: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Where the `nginx-servers` in the host would correspond to an inventory group block that would be defined like so:

```
[nginx-servers]
nginx1.example.com
nginx2.example.com
```

With this you might then want to start looking at [roles](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html) which will greatly improve the ability to re-use a lot of the Ansible code you write.

Comment: I tried `ansible all -i "localhost," --connection=local -m template -a "src=nginx.conf.j2 dest=nginx2.conf"` and got `localhost | FAILED => in current versions of ansible, templates are only usable in playbooks`. ansible 1.9.4

Comment: Oh, then there you go, you actually can't use templates outside of a playbook. You should really be using playbooks (and roles) anyway. Ad-hoc commands are not where Ansible's usefulness lies.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this with a bare bones playbook example as well

Comment: You example with `ansible -i "localhost," ...` didn't work for me without `all -i "localhost," --connection=local`. Does it need inventory file too?

Comment: Put the `--connection=local` on the wrong one (the inventory file specifies it's a local connection on the first one) and missed the `all` host pattern. But it's irrelevant because you can't use `template` with Ansible's ad-hoc commands.

Comment: I think it would be clearer to put the "you can't actually do this" at the top of the answer.

Comment: The answer is more that you should use playbooks rather than ad-hoc commands. Ad-hoc commands are only really meant for one off quick things across multiple hosts (such as checking the status of some machines/services)